# Шифр Виженера на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование

Задали написать программу на шифр Виженера. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы он выводил зашифрованное слово?
Нашел способ как сложить массив, но нужно чтобы и конечное значение тоже складывалось. Т.е если слово False, а ключ true, то сложение массивов идёт с 0-3, а индекс четвёртого элемента "e" из первого массива складывается с 0.
Что делать?

```
import string
alphabet = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_letters)}
a = input('Введите текст: ')
b = input('Введите ключ: ')
k = ""
lst_a = []
lst_b = []
for i in a:
    lst_a.append(alphabet.get(i))
print(lst_a)
for i in b:
    lst_b.append(alphabet.get(i))
print(lst_b)
```

Comment: В чем проблема-то? Если нужно сложить, то складывай.

Comment: Проблема в том , что если ключ: 4 буквы а само слово 5 , то сложение идёт элементов с 0-го до 3-го , а 4 символ как был так и останется: Например:                      [17,4,5,6,7]  + [3,6,5,4] = [20,10, 10, 10, 7]

Comment: Я не вижу в коде вообще никакого сложения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В коде представлены две функции реализующие кодирование и декодирование по алгоритму Виженера:

```py
from itertools import cycle

alp = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def encode_vijn(text, keytext):
    f = lambda arg: alp[(alp.index(arg[0])+alp.index(arg[1])%26)%26]
    return ''.join(map(f, zip(text, cycle(keytext))))


def decode_vijn(coded_text, keytext):
    f = lambda arg: alp[alp.index(arg[0])-alp.index(arg[1])%26]
    return ''.join(map(f, zip(coded_text, cycle(keytext))))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильная реализация шифра.

Что можно сделать:

1. Прочитать теорию про [шифр Виженера](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) на Вики.
2. Посмотреть программные реализации.
   http://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter19.html
   или
   https://gist.github.com/dssstr/aedbb5e9f2185f366c6d6b50fad3e4a4
3. Написать свою реализацию.
4. PROFIT

Comment: За ответ благодарю , но это сложная программа для шифра виженера , https://youtu.be/MC_DosCKxdY, вот видео у него программа меньше чем у меня , посмотрите и убедитесь. Что не все программы должны соответствовать github

Comment: Конечно не должны. Но считаю, что сначала нужно понять алгоритм, как он работает и только потом только его реализовать на любом языке программирования.

Answer (score 0):

Шифр Виженера на английском языке, шифрование:

```
    text="hello"
    key="no"
    alpha_eng=[chr(ord('a')+i) for i in range(26)]
    key_opti="".join(list(key)*((len(text)//len(key))+len(key)))
    vizener="".join([alpha_eng[(alpha_eng.index(i)+alpha_eng.index(j))%26] if 
                    (alpha_eng.index(i)+alpha_eng.index(j))//26!=0 else 
                     alpha_eng[alpha_eng.index(i)+alpha_eng.index(j)] for i,j in zip(text,key_opti)])
    print(vizener)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]